# How to make Android aware of a manually added folder in the file system

Tags: android, directory, android-file

to load an external database I have created a folder in my android project with the name 'assets' as this was recommended in many discussions. However, android can't access this folder and tells that the directory does not exist altough it definitely exists at the given path. I get the error message:

"Directory C:/Users/user/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/Bapp/Bapp_Projekt/app/src/main/assets doesn't exist"

altough at that position there is a folder with the name 'assets' that was however manually created and inserted there. Do you know how I can handle that or do I have to create the folder at another path? In this folder I just want to store a manually created database that should be read by the Android app.

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: `However, android can't access this folder` What do you mean with 'android'? Your Android app running on an Android device?

Comment: `C:/Users/user/Projects/.......` That is a path on your Windows development machine. And you are with your device out of town.

Comment: Thanks for your comment blackapps. I just want to test this app with the Android Emulator and when I access the database in the app that is on the shown path I get an error telling that it does not exists

Comment: Apps on an emulator have no access to files on your pc. The same as if you used a real Android device.  C: is a Windows partition and does not even exists on an Android device/emulator or on a Linux computer or a Mac.

Comment: The folder is in the src/main folder of the app and can be seen in the file explorer

Comment: No not of the app but of the project folder for your app on your development machine.

Comment: @blackapps you wrote "Apps on an emulator have no access to files on your pc. " That is not in line with my experience. I have a lot of files on my PC (e.g. image files) that are accessed by the app in the emulator when I put the into the res/drawable folder. The difference now is that I created the folder 'assets' manually and the app thinks it does not exist.

Comment: So the question is how can I tell the app, that the folder and the file in fact exist and it should load the database from this folder

Comment: Before telling you how to solve your problem: Realize what you are doing when you load images from res/raw. Are you using a C:/......./res/raw/.... path there too? If not then tell how.

Comment: When accessing images I use resource files of Android:
int resId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier( "image_", "drawable",  getContext().getPackageName());
        binding.imageView.setBackgroundResource(resId);

Comment: Thanks for your comments and effort blackapps. I really appreciate it. Maybe the solution would be to make a resource file out of the database. Do you know if that is possible and how to do this? Do you think that this is solution of the problem?

Comment: `I have a lot of files on my PC (e.g. image files) that are accessed by the app in the emulator when I put the into the res/drawable folder. ` You should have tested your app once on a real device. And then in the garden with your device show those images. Do you think they would be loaded from your pc then?

Comment: @blackapps: I think the images are included in the app as they are in the drawable folder of the app. So basically I think they can be accessed because when I install the app on an device those image will also be installed. I tried this with another app and it worked

Comment: You have now seen that files which you put in res/raw are packed in your app.apk file. And at runtime they are resources. You load those images from resource. You dont use file paths then. The same with files in assets. They are packed with your apk too. At runtime use the assets manager to read your files.

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your answer and help. How can I make a ressource file out of the external database such that it is included in the app and where shall I save the database

Comment: You did well. You put it in the assets folder.

Comment: Well, I created the assests folder on my own because there was no assets folder available. This causes the problem that the app can't find the directory

Comment: No.  Not at all. And now i'm disapointed as i already first told you not to use a path and certainly not a path on your development machine but to use the assets manager instead. You did not use a path for your images too but treated them as resource.

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your comment and efforts. How can I use the assets manager instead? I do not know anything about the assets manager. How can I access this

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Where in the file system is the 'natural' assets folder? I could not find it this is why I created it on my own in the src/main/ folder which was probably not the correct thing to do

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your answer. Basically I searched for it with the windows search and it did not find anything. Now when I search for it the only assets folder being displayed is the one I created manually in src/main. It just finds another folder called 'merged_assets' in app/build/intermediates but I think that this is not the correct folder. So there is no assets folder as far as I see it (and there has not been one)

Comment: If, using the ide, you right click on the main folder you can open the windows explorer for it... And it is normal to create the assets folder yourself. And.. you knew that path.. so why did you search for it?

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your answer and effort. I really appreciate your help. Well this is what I exactly did. As I could not find the assets folder I created it on my own in the src/main folder. Now there is an assets folder with a database that I copied there. The question now is how I can access this database and make it being included in the app because with the normal path it does not work

Comment: I'm dis'app'ointed again. Use the assets manager to read your file at runtime..

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your answer. Okay, I will try to learn about the assets manager because I have no clue how it works and try to implement it

Comment: Thanks blackapps for your help and effort.